# Angular 4 using "this" in child scope

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

I am passing a function as an input to the child component.
The callback accesses a member of the child component and toggles a value:

```
rowAction(contact) {
  this.currentlySelectedValues.toggle(contact.id);
}
```

The function itself works, but the Angular compiler is complaining because:

```
error TS2339: Property 'currentlySelectedValues' does not exist on type 'SelectListTabComponent'.
```

I know that at the time of declaration `currentlySelectedValues` does not exist on `this` but once the function is passed, it gets the correct scope.

Is there a better / other way to do this? This will not work in production, since the compiler will not build it.

EDIT:

I pass the function like so:

```
<child-component
  [rows]="dataService"
  [initiallySelectedValues]="initiallySelectedValues"
  [columns]="displayColumnsObjects"
  [select]="true"
  [multiSelect]="multiSelect"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChange($event)"
  [rowClickAction]="rowAction">
</child-component>
```

In the child-component I get it as:

```
  @Input() rowClickAction: Function;
```

And finally I check in the component if I have passed one (since it might be not set)

```
  doRowClickAction(row: any): void {
    if (this.rowClickAction) {
      this.rowClickAction(row);
    }
  }
```

Comment: show `currentlySelectedValues`

Comment: passing a function as an input to the child component., what is meaning of this how you are passing via input property ?

Comment: can you please provide some more code

Comment: I added some more code, does that help?

Comment: You should use Output instead of giving a function as an Input

Answer (score 0):

declare `this.currentlySelectedValues =0` or `this.currentlySelectedValues = ""` as per the type of the variable in `ngOninit()`. Then the compiler can detect a valid property before the call itself.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you should really be using an `@Output` property, like pointed out in the comments

**Child**

```
@Output() rowClickedEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  doRowClickAction(row: any)
  {
    if(this.rowClickedEvent)
    {
      this.rowClickedEvent.emit(row);
    }
  }
```

**Parent (html)**

```
<child (rowClickedEvent) = "onRowEvent($event)"
```

**Parent (ts)**

```
onRowEvent(row)
{
    this.valueFromEvent = row;
}
```

This way, you have no problem with `this` and the context.

**Note**

FYI, if you really want to make it work your way using an `Input` property, you could modify your parent component to declare the callback method like this

```
rowAction = (contact) => {
  this.currentlySelectedValues.toggle(contact.id);
}
```

Using this kind of declaration will preserve the calling context, so `this` will refer to the parent component, instead of the child component. But you should really go with `@Output` events

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eetmrh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) showing both methods

Comment: Thank you very much David!
I managed to resolve the issue in a different and better way I think, which didn't have anything to do with the scope.